# stripes does not call the required event handler

Tags: stripes

I'm developing a web application using stripesframework and had an issue. I found a work around but I want to know why it was happening.

I wrote a class like

```
@UrlBinding("/subject/{subject_type}/{subject_name}")
public class SubjectActionBean extends ActionBean {
    private String subjectType;
    private String subjectName;
    @Validate(required = true)
    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    @Validate(required = true)
    public void setSubjectType(String subjectType) {
        this.subjectType = subjectType;
    }
    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution view() {
        return new Resolution();
    }
}
```

where subject_type and subject_name change based on the subject page from which the action was called. So a call would be localhost/subject/applied/math.

Till here it was working fine. The problem happened when I tried to create a remove method

```
@HandlesEvent("remove")
    public void removeSubject() {
}
```

and called it using localhost/subject/applied/math/remove
At this point stripes started complaining that there is no handler to the call and there is also no default handler.

So, I removed "{subject_type}/{subject_name}" in the path and passed them as parameters and inside the method unpacked them using:

```
getContext().getRequest().getParameter();
```

This made the remove method to get called.

My question now why "{subject_type}/{subject_name}" made stripes unable to find the remove method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `@UrlBinding` to the following:

```
@UrlBinding("/subject/{subject_type}/{subject_name}/{$event}")
```

Without the `{$event}` Stripes is not able tell which part of the URL parameter is supposed to be the event.

Also, to test you can try (with the current `@UrlBinding`) to access `localhost/subject/applied/math?remove=`

Hope that helps.